# Payer and Receiver Swaption

Tags: interest-rate-swap

What is a delta of a payer and a receiver swaption? Is it negative for receiver swaption and positive delta for payer swaption?

Comment: How do you define Delta? (w.r.t. the forward swap?) Intuitively a Receiver Swaption gains in value as interest rates go down, a Payer Swaption gains in value as i.r. go up.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

understand it implies received the fixed leg, hence the delta would be negative for the receiver and positive for the payer.

Comment: understand, edited the reply, thank you